# Gradle/Groovy closure scope confusion

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm new to Gradle/Groovy and am running into issues with variable name resolution in nested closures. I have a custom task class that defines some properties and I am instantiating potentially multiple tasks of that type using a closure. This closure defines a variable named the same as one of the properties in the custom task class and I am running into some odd behavior which seems to go against what is defined in the Groovy language guide. Could someone please answer the questions in the code below?

```
class Something extends DefaultTask {
    def thing = "a"
}
/*
def thing = "b" // produces the error message:
                // > Could not find method b() for arguments [build_63hfhkn4xq8gcqdsf98mf9qak$_run_closure1@70805a56] on root project 'gradle-test'.
                // ...why?
*/
(1..1).each {
    def thing = "c"
    task ("someTask${it}", type: Something) {
        println resolveStrategy == Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST // prints "true"
        println delegate.class // prints "class Something_Decorated"
        println thing // prints "c" shouldn't this be "a" since it's using DELEGATE_FIRST?
        /*
        println owner.thing // produces the error message:
                            // > Could not find property 'thing' on root project 'gradle-test'
                            // shouldn't the "owner" of this closure be the enclosing closure?
                            // in that case shouldn't this resolve to "c"
        */
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
For some reason after changing all of the `def` into `String` and then back into `def` I can no longer replicate the `def thing = "b"` line producing that weird error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code prints `c` because the variable named `thing` is declared within the lexical scope of the closure. It means that closure can just use the value of this variable. What will work:

1. Renaming the `thing` variable defined in the closure.
2. Explicitly referring to `thing` via `delegate`:

   `println delegate.thing`

Comment: so it will only use the delegation strategy (mentioned in section [3.2.4 of the Groovy Language Guide](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html)) if it cannot first find the name in the lexical scope of the closure?

Comment: As far as I understood it, yes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Also, that weird error I was getting on the `def thing = "b"` line seems to have went away after I changed all of the `def` into `String` and then back into `def` (now it's just procuding an error saying that `thing` is already defined at the `def thing = "c"` line which makes a lot more sense)... so I'm going to assume that one was some weird bug or something.